# Dynamic Time Table in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am new to android. I wish to create a time table in android based on user input. users have to enter the number of days and the number of lectures per day. That is dynamic rows as well as columns. after the inputs a table is to be displayed and the user should fill in the details of time table which are to be stored in a file. 
Is this possible using the TableLayout, or is there any other better way?
Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648126/dynamically-update-values-in-table-android is possibly your salvation.

Comment: thanks Chris Zhang ... i found a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443414/adding-a-dynamic-tablelayout-with-borders-in-a-android-app